# Using ogr2ogr to clip shapefile based on coordinate query

Tags: gdal, geojson, ogr2ogr

I have some shapefiles that I would like to convert to GeoJSON and clip to display only Arctic regions (for example, everything above 45°N).

I tried the following, but nothing is clipped.

Any suggestions?

`ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON land.json -spat -180 0 180 45 land.shp`

and

`ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON land.json -clipsrcwhere "y<45" land.shp`

Clearly I'm grasping at straws. I haven't been able to find examples of `clipsrcwhere` in any of my searches. Not sure if it is the right option, but my region is not exactly rectangular.

Comment: -clipsrcwhere is for a SQL query when a clip source feature class (-clipsrc datasource) is specified. You can use -clipsrc -180 45 180 90 to *clip* your data to only the area north of 45 degrees (at the moment your -spat is anything from the Equator to 45N but not clipping); It's important to make a distinction between -clipsrc and -spat, spat is a selection without a clip but clipsrc trims off any excess and will take arguments in many forms (read https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) for more info.. but first what CRS is your input data in? is land.shp in geographic coordinates?

Comment: The input file is in WGS84 coordinates. The option you suggested seems to help, thanks. With this coordinate system I used -clipsrc -180 60 180 90 to include only areas north of the Arctic circle

Comment: That's great news, can you now answer your own question with links and a screen shot of the input and output data for the benefit of future readers; If I put in an answer it wouldn't be as nice, I don't have any pretty data north of the Equator to show anyone.